# How to center multiple of the same Images horizontally in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

With the code below I'm trying to make it print out the same image 19 times and then have those 19 images as a whole centered horizontally on the page, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
var totImg = "large.png"; 

function prettyHeader(){
    function totoroImg(){
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.style.width = "30px";
        img.style.height = "30px";

        img.src=totImg;
        return img;
    }

    for(var totPrint=0; totPrint<20; totPrint++){
        document.body.appendChild(totoroImg());
    }
}

prettyHeader();
```

Comment: I wonder if either css grid or flexbox might be helpful to you? Here is a fav [tutorial on flexbox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc). If you are unfamiliar, seriously take the time to do that flexbox tut. Super useful for layout, and super easy as explained in that vid.

Comment: @gibberish Thanks man, but I'm more looking for if there's a way to view those 19 images in the function as a whole in Javascript and center it.

Comment: Think about how you would do this if the images where part of the document in the HTML to begin with, and not added dynamically via JavaScript. Then apply that same solution to your images that got added dynamically.

Comment: @misorude That's the issue I can't seem to figure out how to add rules to that function to make all those images centered. Would you be able to explain what I should do.

Comment: _“Would you be able to explain what I should do.”_ - I just did that, didn’t I? Step number 1: Find a solution to display images centered in the way you want them to be, with a static HTML/CSS example, without involving any script at this point. Once you got that, you can start thinking about how to get your script to dynamically produce the same.

Comment: That's the issue I can't seem to figure out how to make the script produce the same, the closest I got was each image centered but they were one under the other rather than on the same line centered.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var totImg = "https://placeimg.com/30/30/animals";

function prettyHeader(){
function totoroImg(){
var img =document.createElement("img");
img.style.width= "30px";
img.style.height="30px";

img.src=totImg;
return img;
}

for(var totPrint=0; totPrint<20; totPrint++){
document.body.appendChild(totoroImg());
}
}

prettyHeader();

document.body.style = "display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-direction: row";
```

Comment: Adding that new line just seems to add a giant white square in the middle of the page with the 19 images offset to the right

Comment: Adding that line works 100%. You might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Yeah thank you very much I mistakenly added it to the wrong line.

Comment: Only having one more issue, is that whenever I try to add anything else such as another seperate image or text it trys to place it on the same line as those 19 images, how would I seperate them?

Comment: create a `div` as a container and place those images inside of a div. The same for the other thing you are doing. But you have to change the styles for everything. You really need to take a look at flexbox.

Comment: Thanks that flexbox tutorial was really useful, it helped me make it work.